# Creating Permanent Loop in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop, circular-reference

I wrote an Adobe AIR app that behaves like this:

User logs in and a permanent loop is created using setTimeout. This loop performs an HTTP request, compares a json md5 string that is returned to a global variable. If these two values differ, the dom is updated with new content. When the user performs another action such as sending a reply or deleting a message, a silent update is performed and this "pauses" the loop. It's basically like a simple email client.

The way I'm doing it is unreliable and causes memory leaks. I plan on rewriting it from the ground up, and I don't want to end up in the same boat that I'm in now. If anyone could give me examples of how they would do it or give me any advice, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't poll that often but use a technique known as "long polling" or "COMET". Basically you send a request which will stay open until there's a response due to updated data etc. or a timeout. After some response was received, you immediately send a new request.

This saves lots of bandwidth and server load as it drastically reduces the amount of requests sent.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't an option for me, although it's a good suggestion. I'm currently retrieving the data by scraping an html page, and I don't think I'll need to handle more than 1000 concurrent users which I have the spare resources to handle.


Could you give any suggestions on how to do the loop from the client side?